# Taking blame though I'm not at fault

Tags: word-choice

Got transferred to Tokyo by my company, and the trains are late almost everyday. When trains are late in the morning we send an email stating that we'll be late.

Customarily we end the mail with "ご迷惑おかけしますが、よろしくお願い致します。"

Writing it like this feels like I'm taking the blame for something totally out of my control.

Can I place the blame where it actually belongs, ending with something like "JR東がご迷惑おかけしてますが、よろしくお願い致します。"?

Comment: In English I would most likely just state that the trains are running late so I'll be delayed.

Comment: Also how about 〇〇のせいで遅くなります。宜しくお願いします。

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "Can I place the blame where it actually belongs" in a professional communication is a problem of manners, more appropriate for the Workplace Stack Exchange. Otherwise the question should be rephrased to "I want to sound utterly unprofessional; with what words can I achieve that in Japanese?"

Comment: @macraf I don't believe it's off-topic, because I'm asking about the content, not the context. If it was the circumstances surrounding sending the email instead of the content of the email I would have gone to Workplace-SE.

Comment: @macraf I disagree. Accurately describing a situation/spinning a situation is an important part of business language. For example in English you wouldn't want to say "I'm sorry that my train is late. I apologize for inconveniencing you." Instead you might say something like "The chuo line is running late, but I'll get started on whatever I can from in the train. Thanks for understanding."

Comment: @Leo If you are late in a professional situation it is your fault. There are many corporate cultures in which your suggested English excuse would be your last one. It has nothing to do with the language unless the question described precisely the intention.

Comment: @macraf I absolutely agree with you. The language deemed valid is closely related to the culture and and such it is a valid question.

Comment: No it's not a valid question, because it asks "can I" and doesn't describe the intention of the message, thus the answers must be based on a different set of rules: manners, specifically business manners. I suggested an amendment to improve the question. You posted two comments in response "I disagree" then "I agree". I'm confused..

Comment: @Yushi _"Writing it like this feels like I'm taking the blame for something totally out of my control."_ It's not totally out of your control. If the trains have a consistent habit of being late, I'd say you should adjust to this and start your commute a bit earlier. A delayed train can still get you to work on time if you catch the right one. You should at least try to find a coworker who takes the same train line and ask how they handle the situation.

Comment: @JLRishe view previous comments. I already plan for a 10-15 minute delay. Planning for anything over that doesn't seem reasonable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Japanese people say ご迷惑をおかけします and 申し訳ありません even when they are not to blame. As long as you adequately describe the situation, no one will think you are to blame. Likewise, when a Japanese person says ご迷惑をおかけします, すみません, 申し訳ありません or *I'm sorry*, you should not take it for granted that they admitted a fault. Saying JR東がご迷惑おかけしていますが in this situation sounds funny at least.

After all, JR East is saying 電車が遅れまして大変申し訳ありません all the time even when the company is not to blame at all. If heavy snow stopped a train, a conductor  usually says ご迷惑をおかけしています. If someone jumped in front of a train, the company says 大変申し訳ありません. That's what JR East is expected to say as a reliable company, and that's also what you are expected to say as a responsible businessperson.

Comment: Good points. Explains the connotation behind the phrase.

Comment: "Japanese people say ご迷惑をおかけします and 申し訳ありません even when they are not to blame." How far do you think that this actually extends? For example: If a bird pooped on a restaurant guest would the server say ご迷惑をかけしました？ If another customer spilled beer on me would the waitstaff apologize to me? If the electricity went out and I couldn't do a powerpoint presentation should I say ご迷惑をかけました？ I think this is the core of the problem. Obviously the "apologies" can extend to things outside of your control but exactly how far do they go and how much of the responsibility are you actually taking?

Comment: @Leo that's true, but if we start debating the extent I'm not sure we could get a definite answer and seems like it would become speculation. If it was in legal terms would be interested in the level of responsibility though...

Comment: IMO... "If a bird pooped on a restaurant guest" → This may not be a good example because I think the restaurant should control it. "If another customer spilled beer on me" → No, it's the customer who have to say sorry. "If the electricity went out" → Yes, you can naturally say すみません/ご迷惑を… although you don't have to.

Comment: @naruto Hard to control bird poop if a restaurant provides outdoor seating, but I'm pretty sure a restaurant employee would apologize with something like 申し訳ありません even if a bird did poop on a patron in their outdoor seating. Now, if a bird is pooping on customers _inside_ their restaurant, that's quite a different problem.

Comment: @naruto Thanks for your insight. It's funny to me how if someone jumps in front of a train an apology is expected but if a patron spills a beer on someone else an apology is not expected, while both of which are somewhat out of control of the businesses. Is ご迷惑をかけしました a "real" apology? Is it just an empty phrase that is expected to be said? What is really being communicated? As far as I understand it means "We recognize that you are inconvenienced but doesn't necessarily mean that there is any recognition of fault, introspection or remorse." Would you say that this is accurate?

Comment: @Leo any one of your examples *can* (reasonably or not) be thought of as the fault of the business owner. Snow on tracks → could have engineered better trains. Suicide by train → could have made it more difficult to get on the tracks in the first place. Bird poop → could have sealed off outdoor seating better. Another customer spilling beer → could have had more space / separators between customers. Even natural disasters can be expected by some degree. Not designing/engineering against it is taking a risk. Now, whether you would actually be responsible depends on laws/agreements.